# Does Ubuntu offer tactile sign language accessibility options for persons both blind and deaf?

Tags: accessibility

Persons both blind and deaf often rely on tactile sign language, feeling the hands of the person using sign language (because they can't see the signs). Does Ubuntu offer a software that could assist such persons, by operating a  set of robotic hands attached to the system as a peripheral device?
This is not concerning braille, it is specifically for tactile sign language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly, Ubuntu does not offer this accessibiliiy option, the technology I don't think is publicly available for such robotic hands, but definitely no features on Ubuntu support this. Maybe in the future. Hopefully, this would very helpful, but not now.